# Adding content of one Jpanel into another - Java Swings

Tags: java, swing

I have a method which returns a jpanel with a layout set like a image carousel. I have checked and this code works fine on a single `JPanel` when directly applied. But the same layout is being used in multiple places. Hence I wanted to create a generic method that sets this layout and returns a `jPanel`. This is the method I wrote:

```
public static JPanel loadImages(String Location) throws IOException{
    JPanel ImagePanel = new JPanel();
      File directory = new File(Location);
     ImageIcon image;

     String[] imageFiles = directory.list();
    DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();   
     JLabel lab1=new JLabel();
      JCheckBox  chkbox ; 
    ImagePanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 

    for (int ii=0; ii<imageFiles.length; ii++) {
       GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();  
        image = new ImageIcon(imageFiles[ii]);
            lab1 = new JLabel(image);
        constraint.gridx = ii;
        constraint.gridy =0;  
        ImagePanel.add(lab1,constraint);
    }
    for (int ii=0; ii<imageFiles.length; ii++) {
        GridBagConstraints constraint1 = new GridBagConstraints();         
        constraint1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;           
        chkbox = new JCheckBox(imageFiles[ii]);
        constraint1.gridx = ii;
        constraint1.gridy =1;

        ImagePanel.add(chkbox, constraint1);
      }  
    return ImagePanel;

  }
```

My idea was that in all the places where this is required , I would have a jscrollpane already set in the UI. And I wanted to call this method which would return this JPanel and I wanted to add this to the scroll pane.

```
private void jRadioButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      jScrollPane3.add(loadImages("C://users//images"));
      jScrollPane3.revalidate();
      jScrollPane3.repaint();
 }
```

But nothing is displayed. Is it because the layout is not set?

Comment: What kind of layout does jScrollPane3 use?

Comment: I have not set the layout . So i am guessing the default layout..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use add on the JScrollPane.

Try:

```
jScrollPane3.setViewportView(loadImages("C://users//images"));
```

Comment: Short answer, that's just how JScrollPanes work.  
See the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)